# How to preset elements of dynamic mat-select as selected in Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm building an edit form which contains multiple, multiple-choice select fields being built dynamically.

Updated code:

```
<mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="dispoArray[clase.nombre]" name="clase.nombre" (selectionChange)="withoutDispositivo()"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let dispo of clase.dispositivos" [(value)]="dispo.id">
        {{ dispo.descripcion }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This is the function in charge of building these fields,

Updated code:

```
prepareClaseDispositivo() {
    this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
        if (!this.labelDispositivos.includes(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre)) {
            this.labelDispositivos.push(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre);
        }
    });
    this.labelDispositivos.forEach(clase => {
        let arrayByClase = new Array();
        this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
            if (clase === dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre) {
                if (this.passedData.dispositivos) {
                    for (const d of this.passedData.dispositivos) {
                        if (d.descripcion == dispo.descripcion) {
                            this.dispoArrayValue.push({ id: d.id, descripcion: d.descripcion });
                        }
                    }
                }
                arrayByClase.push({ id: dispo.id, descripcion: dispo.descripcion });
            }
        });
        let json = { nombre: clase, dispositivos: arrayByClase };
        this.dispoByClase.push(json);
    });
}
```

My question is, how can I pre-set the options that are found in the array coming from the database as selected when the form is being built?

Comment: The app is pretty complex and is working alongside laravel and postgresql to fetch data needed for comparison. Unsure if I can share all of it on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pre-populate a `mat-select` when using `ngModel`, set the model value to your selections. For example:

HTML

```
<mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS

```
selected = ['option1', 'option3'];
```

Comment: How can I add these model values dynamically as I find coincidences within the data in DB and the form fields being built?

Comment: When you load your data, set the values in the model.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about it the wrong way. Still, I'm not able to make it work, could you maybe take a look at the updated code in the OP and see if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The values you push need to be the same as the `mat-option` `value` setting: `this.dispoArrayValue.push(d.id);` because `<mat-option *ngFor="let dispo of clase.dispositivos" [(value)]="dispo.id">`.